# SetValue on property doesn't update object

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo

I cannot figure out why this is not working. Can anyone explain to me why SetValue does not set the value of my object's properties?

```
T row = new T();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in row.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
{
    Field[] dbFields = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Field), false) as Field[];

    Object obj = (Int32)1000; // Arbitrary Value;
    Object castObj = Convert.ChangeType(obj, property.PropertyType);

    property.SetValue(row, castObj, null); // DOES NOT UPDATE row!! WHY!?
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're using an [evil mutable value type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).  
Don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work fine so long as `T` is a reference type (a class). It won't work as-is if `T` is a value type (a struct). The value will be boxed on each call to `property.SetValue`, and the existing value would remain untouched. Is it possible that that's the problem? If so, I'd urge you to avoid writing mutable value types in the first place - consider making it a reference type instead.

You *could* just force it to be boxed once, then unboxed once at the end - but if I were you I'd just steer well clear of mutable value types.

Comment: This is exactly my problem, my objects are structs (I come form a C++ background and totally forgot that they are treated differently in C#). Thank you!

Comment: @MarkP: So are you able to just change them to classes? Hopefully that should just solve your problem...